# Feature request: real time code compilation

Tags: feature-request, code

Interactive / Real time code compilation for stackoverflow.com. That will improve the answer correctness of the stackoverflow.com.

When adding a new code block, let the user try to compile the code and see the result. It will be useful to demonstrate class designs, algorithms, and logics.

Comment: So, you are going to ask SO to support all the many thousands of compiled languages out there?

Comment: no. they can pick languages to support. It is for simple code demonstration only. Or, they can even create their own language. Languages with dynamic code generation can support this basically without too much effort.

Comment: How about __Wasabi__?

Comment: @gilbertc How does creating their own language help???

Comment: What I meant was to have a common language to show the idea of the code without ambiguity. The language does not need to be C#, or any production language.

Comment: @gilbertc This language is going to "without ambiguity" be able to demonstrate all the features of C#, C++, LISP, Haskell, COBOL and Perl (to name a only few very popular languages)? I don't think so.

Comment: @Neil Agreed, though I'd like to see codepad.org feature integrated into SO as suggested in answers below.

Comment: It's worth noting that this feature, or one very similar to it was endorsed by [Jon Skeet on SE podcast #4](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/se-podcast-04/) - see jim-mkeeth's comment at 60.30. (I don't think it's possible to direct link to a point in time in soundcloud?).  I'm surprised this question hasn't been voted higher, as Jon said, this would be **really** cool.

Comment: How about taking advantage of this? https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki

Comment: I really don't see this as such a massive technical challenge, there are services like ideone that can just be re-used. All that is really needed is cross integration. I think its relatively simple, and will give significant benefits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is already a solved problem, use [codepad.org](http://codepad.org).

Comment: No C#? Bummer...

Comment: that is exactly what i am looking for. but it would be nice if SO has this feature integrated.

Comment: @Robert: Yeah, it would be much improved with support for C# and Java (and other CLR or JVM based languages). I sent a request to the author a while ago but never heard back.

Comment: If you want to test compile C++ snippets, the place to go is http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/

Comment: @Robert, [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/) has online C# compilation (and execution of the compiled sources).

Answer (score 17):

That's a pretty big technical challenge that would provide very little return, in my opinion.

Beside, people are *discouraged* from posting entire bodies of working code. You should limit your posts to just enough relevant code to describe the problem.

Comment: Imagine if we have a collaborative platform with a real-time compiler, code can be modified and updated and optimized without giving up any correctness. I think that return is big enough to justify the technical challenge, if any.

Comment: I'm trying to imagine but I'm just not seeing it. I don't speak for SO but I can't recall any of my posts where this would have resulted in a better Q&A experience. Sorry. It never hurts to ask, though.

Comment: "People are discouraged from posting entire bodies of working code" - really? I always try (don't always succeed) to post compilable code.

Comment: Maybe my idea of having a mini- open source platform for a Q&A site is too far from ideal...

Comment: But @Neil, I'm willing to bet you post compilable *abstracts* that only exhibit the feature or problem at issue, right? Which we all appreciate. As opposed to the all too common "It doesn't work!" posts that include two to four files totaling more than a hundred lines of code.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see why not. An AJAX request could be made, sending the code back to the server to be compiled to LLVM bytecode, which could then be distributed to and executed within the browser of anyone who views the question. This takes much of the complexity of the problem away from SO servers. As a proof of concept, consider [this demo](https://kripken.github.io/llvm.js/demo.html), which is actually excessive for the requirements of this problem as it assembles plain-text LLVM assembly, an unnecessary task when the server is sending pre-assembled programs.