# Can we get these IDEOne/Run-This executable widgets installed on Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Feature request: real time code compilation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38971/feature-request-real-time-code-compilation)

Hey, I recently came across this awesome set of widgets from IDEOne (http://ideone.com/) that allow you to have executable code snippets in webpages. I immediately thought Stack Overflow could benefit from this power and was about to start building a greasemonkey script to add them, but first figured I'd give Jeff and others the option to embed this natively.

Anyway, here's the demo page: http://run-this.appspot.com/

(Disclaimer: I'm not in any way affiliated with any of these people. Just thought the widget was cool and wanted it to work inside of Stack Overflow).

*EDIT* I appreciate all the wonderful down votes and "answers" that have nothing at all to do with what I'm really asking for, so I'll just assume that for whatever reason StackOverflow users that actually interact on meta just don't like this idea. I'll try to throw together a greasemonkey script. Once that's done, I'll post a link to it here.

Comment: Discussed here: real time code compilation (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38971/feature-request-real-time-code-compilation)

Comment: That's not at all what I'm asking. I'm SPECIFICALLY asking for this IDEOne widget to be implemented on the pages. Did you even go to http://run-this.appspot.com? Heh. You add a few javascript libraries and add the lang="" attribute to the code element and it does everything for you. Thanks though.

Comment: Asking for a specific version of a general request that has been shot down is *not* new or different.

Comment: All I get on the demo page are spinny discs that spin forever when I click the `RUN!` buttons. 

Please don't integrate alpha or beta software unless there's a significantly compelling reason.

Answer (score 7):

The problem with this idea is that users will be encouraged to post entire bodies of working code just to illustrate a point that would probably be **better expressed in a short snippet**.

I wouldn't want to encourage that.

You should limit your posts to just enough relevant code to describe the problem. I can't recall any of my posts where this would have resulted in a better Q&A experience.

Comment: Why would they be encouraged to do that? This widget will execute any code you pass it and spit back the results. If they're having a problem getting a regular expression to work, they can paste what they have and it will show the output that is incorrect. Then, any code that the users post will instantly be seen as valid.

Comment: "This widget will execute any code you pass" Oh goodie....

Answer (score 3):

As much as I like the idea on paper, I get this queasy feeling every time I think of letting anyone put executable code on someone else's page...

Comment: Look at the link though. The code is not "executable". It's a direct link to the IDEOne interpreters. They "run" the code and just display the output and execution time.

Comment: @Eric: Based on the way you explained it, I was not about to go to a site that "allow you to have executable code snippets in webpages" from my work computer. When I get home, and am using an isolated VM, maybe. But not from work.